# FlutterFire's Google authentication saving last account selection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am developing a Flutter app with Firebase and i am using google's authentication.
I'm encountering a problem where, after signing in with a google account, on the next time i trigger the google authentication, the account selection popup does not appear, and the last selected account is chosen again by default.
How can i prevent such behavior, and trigger the account selection popup every time?

Comment: You need signout in both, firebase Auth and Google.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

@jorge is right

You have to calls the sign-out for both **google** as well as **firebase**

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
```